# Stop Windows 10 Fullscreen Popup

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-v1703, popups, windows-10-v1709

So today i was playing a game of CS in which i got a Windows 10 Update notice like this:

[image]

This was quite bad since i ran CS in Full screen and the Popup just placed on top of the Game window and completely threw me off.

Is there a way to stop this from appearing?
If not, is there at least a way to make it open in the Background (kind of like Windows 7)?

I only found [this guide](https://winaero.com/blog/disable-updates-available-windows-10/), which I'm not so sure about working and possible side effects.

How do you guys get around this?

I am running Windows 10 Professional Version 1803 after the update. 
I either ran 1703 or 1709 when i was getting this popup. (not quite sure about that)

Comment: Disable the Windows Update Service prior to gaming, re enable it when you are not gaming.

Comment: @Moab to be honest I'm looking for a more appealing solution, which doesn't require actions everytime I'm playing.

Comment: good luck......

Comment: That's strange. If you are running 1803, you're not supposed to get that alert at all. That's the alert for _installing_ 1803.

Comment: @EUserNameError my bad there, i'am running 1803 after the update, ran 1703 or 1709 before, not sure about that, i'll edit the question

Comment: You won't have to worry about this for about half a year. Plus v1803 is tamer. Now, I recommend you set Active Hours in Settings app, the Updates section. Set them so that they cover the 18 hours that you are awake. That should take care of this notice.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood, your problem is with the pop u, right?

In this case you will need to activate a feature called "Gaming Mode", it prevents pop up and other applications from disturbing you while playing and let the pc focus its resources on the game.

To activate it, press Windows key + G

[image]

Alternatively, You may try [Game Booster](https://www2.razer.com/cortex/boost) which upon opening a game, it will activate **Game Booster** where it will temporary disable unnecessary services and softwares (including windows update) until you exit the game.

Comment: Have you confirmed that Game Mode will prevent the prompt the author received?  Game Mode is more about improving performance within a game, while it will silence some notifications, the prompt the author received does not appear to be a toast notification.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, cant exactly confirm this on win10 as I'm using windows 7, but i have faced such situation while playing games and solved my pops and notifications by enabling "Game mode" from 3rd party softwares..that's why i mentioned it.