# Turn off Windows 10 "Activate Windows" fullscreen popup

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-activation, popups, windows-10-v2004

My copy of Windows 10 is not activated, due to errors involving multiple Windows resets (from an already activated copy of Windows). As a result, every so often (every 2 hours or so) I get a big, blue fullscreen popup saying to activate Windows. This popup doesn't allow any sort of inputs until the "Go to Settings" button appears a few seconds later. It's intrusive, especially when I'm working on something or playing a game.

Photo of screen because print screen doesn't work when the popup is on screen:
[image: Activate Windows popup]

Is there a way to turn this off?

I've seen [this Superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/1321971/stop-windows-10-fullscreen-popup) regarding disabling *update* popups, but I imagine the process would be similar, if the activation popup uses a similar method.

I've also tried poking through the registry, and found in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SoftwareProtectionPlatform\Activation` fields called `ActivationInterval`, `Manual`, and `NotificationDisabled`, which I wonder if will do anything.

Windows 10 version 2004, build 19041.1.

Comment: Activate it. Windows isn't freeware.

Comment: Also, if you copied this installation around or something, it may be better to start from scratch, in case some software component is damaged.